# Difference between System.import() and import()?

Tags: javascript, import, webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-2

In [webpack 1 docs is statement](http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#es6-modules) that in webpack 2 will use `System.import()` for dynamic require:

> Luckily, there is a JavaScript API “loader” specification being
>   written to handle the dynamic use case: `System.load` (or
>   **`System.import`**). This API will be the native equivalent to the above
>   `require` variations.

And during that time all around the web was [examples](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#importing-modules-and-loading-scripts) of using this `System.import()`.

---

[Before releasing webpack 2](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v2.1.0-beta.28), authors decide to change `System.import()` to `import()`:

> add `import()` as Code Splitting construct. It should be used instead of
>   `System.import` when possible. `System.import` will be deprecated in
>   webpack 2 release (removed in webpack 3) **as it's behavior is incorrect
>   according to the spec**.

This `import()` is based on [tc39/proposal-dynamic-import](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) specification, and you can read more why they made this change [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2163).

---

**Can someone explain difference between `System.import()` and `import()`?**

Despite different name, usage looks the same:

```js
import(modulePath)
  .then(module => module.default())
  .catch(/* ... */);

System.import(modulePath)
  .then(module => module.default())
  .catch(/* ... */);
```

But in weback 2 doc is: "`System.import()` behavior is incorrect according to the spec" - so it suggest that there is difference between `System.import()` and `import()`.

Comment: If I am reading the links you have provided right, a very important difference is that `import()` is aware of the script or module that invoked it, while `System.import()` is not. If I am right, this means that `import('../foo')`, i.e. resolution relative to the current module, is possible. Then again I might be badly mistaken, please correct me.

Comment: It looks like the difference originated from [this github issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2163)

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you're looking for:  [tc39 Proposal for Import](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import#an-actual-function)

> An actual function
>
> Drafts of the Loader ideas collection have at various times had actual functions (not just function-like syntactic forms) named System.import() or System.loader.import() or similar, which accomplish the same use cases.
>
> The biggest problem here, as previously noted by the spec's editors, is how to interpret the specifier argument to these functions. Since these are just functions, which are the same across the entire Realm and do not vary per script or module, the function must interpret its argument the same no matter from where it is called. (Unless something truly weird like stack inspection is implemented.) So likely this runs into similar problems as the document base URL issue for the importModule function above, where relative module specifiers become a bug farm and mismatch any nearby import declarations.